# Neural Network loss drastically jumps during training

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

During training of my LSTM network the loss/acc went from 0.75/85% to 4.97/17% from the 42 epoch to the 44 epoch.

[image]

Why would this happen?

I only have 1500 training examples currently and am overfitting heavily. Would this be a cause?

For context I am using keras and a lstm network to predict reactions to text on slack. My training data are label encoded sentences and I am predicting the reaction class which is just a one hot representation of all the possible classes.

Here is my model in Keras

```
# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_message_length))
model.add(LSTM(1024))
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

The loss and accuracy end up recovering by the 100th epoch. Is this something to worry about?

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:

import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import os 
pd.options.display.max_columns = 999
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 999

np.random.seed(7)


# In[2]:

raw_data = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir('data/random'):
    temp_df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf='data/random/' + file, orient='values', dtype=False)
    raw_data = pd.concat([raw_data, temp_df])

for file in os.listdir('data/company-wide'):
    temp_df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf='data/company-wide/' + file, orient='values', dtype=False)
    raw_data = pd.concat([raw_data, temp_df])

for file in os.listdir('data/politics'):
    temp_df = pd.read_json(path_or_buf='data/politics/' + file, orient='values', dtype=False)
    raw_data = pd.concat([raw_data, temp_df])


# In[3]:

raw_data.shape


# In[4]:

# Only selected messages with reactions
data = raw_data.loc[(raw_data['reactions'].isnull() == False) & (raw_data['text'] != '')][['reactions', 'text']]


# In[5]:

data.shape


# In[6]:

def extractEmojiName(x):
    max_count = 0
    result = ''
    for emoji in x:
        if (emoji['count'] > max_count):
            result = emoji['name']
    return result

def removeUrls(x):
    line = re.sub(r"<(http|https).*>", "", x)
    return line

def removeUsername(x):
    line = re.sub(r"<@.*>", "", x)
    return line


# In[7]:

data['reactions_parsed'] = data['reactions'].apply(lambda x: extractEmojiName(x))


# In[8]:

data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: removeUrls(x))
data['text'] = data['text'].apply(lambda x: removeUsername(x))


# In[9]:

max_words = 10000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nb_words=max_words)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['text'])
text_vectors = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['text'])
data['text_vector'] = text_vectors


# In[10]:

encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['reactions_encoded'] = encoder.fit_transform(data['reactions_parsed'])


# In[11]:

data


# In[12]:

classes = len(data['reactions_parsed'].unique())

target_vector = data['reactions_encoded'].values
reactions_vector = np.eye(classes)[target_vector]
data['reactions_vector'] = reactions_vector.tolist()


# In[13]:

max_message_length = data['text_vector'].apply(lambda x: len(x)).max()


# In[14]:

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(text_vectors, reactions_vector, test_size=.2, stratify=reactions_vector)


# In[15]:

X_train = np.array(X_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
y_test = np.array(y_test)


# In[17]:

X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_message_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_message_length)


# In[18]:

# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 128
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_message_length))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(1024))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(classes, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


# In[ ]:

model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=35, batch_size=64)


# In[ ]:

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))


# In[45]:

scores


# In[56]:

def show_predictions(model, X_test, y_test):
    predictions = model.predict(X_test)

    index = 0
    for prediction in predictions:
        print('Prediction -> ' + encoder.inverse_transform(prediction.argmax()))
        print('Actual -> ' + encoder.inverse_transform(y_test[index].argmax()))
        index+=1


# In[57]:

show_predictions(model, X_test, y_test)


# In[58]:

show_predictions(model, X_train[0:100], y_train[0:100])


# In[ ]:
```

Comment: Have this happened only once? Or it happens every time you restart your training? And what is your `batch_size`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko It appears to be doing it every time around the 42nd epoch. My batch_size is 64 and I am running on Google Cloud Nvidia K80 GPU instance.

Comment: This is really weird. Could you provide us a full training code?

Comment: The full code is posted above. I have not been checking every time as training takes a while but it did happen all 3 times the first time i checked.

Comment: Try to set different random seed.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko that seems to have fixed it. Side question I am severely overfitting 86% acc train vs 50% test. I have added dropout which helped and want to add regularization but when I did it seemed to stop learning. The loss was barely changing after each epoch where as without i can achieve 86% train accuracy after 35 epochs.

Comment: Try making your net wider - by increasing the layers size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137970/discussion-between-wwoodal1-and-marcin-mozejko).